# simple_form span after checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

when using simple_form in rails, there is always a span element added after a checkbox input element. I've looked into wrappers, but no matter what I do, span element is always there.

I've even tried my own wrapper. No luck.

I've problems because a theme expects something like this:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-styled">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <span>Remember me</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

And simple_form generates something like this:

```
<input value="0" type="hidden" name="user[remember_me]">
<span></span>
<label class="boolean optional" for="user_remember_me">
  <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[remember_me]" id="user_remember_me">
  <span></span>Remember me
</label>
```

EDIT - view code, very basic, with default wrapper (using bootstrap wrappers doesn't change they way it works, too):

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean %>
```

So, effectively i get two checkbox elements and one label "Remember me"
Now, how do I remove the span element?
Why is it there anyway?

Thx

Comment: please paste your rails view code also.

Comment: <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean %>